# Should root own files in rbenv directories?

Tags: ruby, permissions, rubygems, rbenv

Today I was trying to install a jekyll's gem using:

```
gem install jekyll
```

And I got some permission errors:

```
$ gem install jekyll
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir -  /Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/ffi-1.9.10
```

Well, I checked and indeed that file as well as a lot of other ones are owned by root.

Is that correct? Should root own files under rbenv's root directory? Can I fix this by using `chown` recursively to change everything under ~/.rbenv to my user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, root should not own any file in ~/.rbenv. Probably it caused by some unneeded `sudo` usage. You can safely `chown` the files in the directory.

Comment: Cool! Thanks... I did a recursive chown to set the files to my user and everything is working fine now... indeed I think I mistakenly ran a sudo gem install in the past that could cause this. Thanks again!

Comment: `sudo gem install` most likely wouldn't cause the problem. Perhaps you used `sudo` to install a Ruby using rbenv. But it's safe to run `sudo chown -R $USER ~/.rbenv` which will return ownership to you.